# Intl.DateTimeFormat().format() generates inconsistent strings

Tags: javascript

So I have the following code:

```
let datetime_created = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ve', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric'
}).format(new Date())
console.log(datetime_created)
// should output something like "9/20/2022, 12:21:22 PM"
```

This variable is later stored in a database and everything looked fine, but once the app was put in production and records were being stored, [some dates had commas, others were being separated by hyphens (-) instead of slashes (/), some had the "AM/PM" marks while others were formatted as "a.m./p.m." and others didn't even had those at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11PXp.png), and needless to say, it was a disaster.

I tried adding a few more options to force the formatting a bit more, such as adding `hour12: false` and a specific timezone, and while it has helped a lot, it still generates inconsistencies sometimes. Why's that and how can I avoid it?

Edit: the problem had to do with the locale (check comments). I'm weirded out by the fact that I don't get a warning message, but anyway. As for why I'm not using an iso string, that's because I was asked to store this date with this specific format.

Comment: Why would you store formatted date in the database instead of iso string?

Comment: What is the "ve" locale? Does it even exist? Also I have to echo @KonradLinkowski - why would you use anything other than the standard ISO 8601 strings?

Comment: @VLAZ I think it is Venezuela but I'm not sure. If it is it should probably be `es-ve`

Comment: @Jacob There is also "vi" for Vietnam. But I could not find a "ve" by itself. And if it doesn't exist, it's ignored and the current locale is used.

Comment: The examples I see usually include a language code like es-VE as otherwise it uses a default.  Anyway, anything going into the DB should be processed server side when possible.

Comment: As @VLAZ noted, if you use an invalid "locale", it will use the browser's current "locale". So what you term "inconsistent" is actually very consistent: All visits from that same browser with that same "locale" will produce the exact same format. The problem is in your code and your expectations, not in Intl.DateTimeFormat (which has its own issues, to be sure, but this is not one of them).

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - because I was asked to do so

Comment: @HereticMonkey - indeed, this does seem to be the case. Shame I can't mark comments as having solved my problem! Thanks to VLAZ for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the inconsistencies but you can achieve the intended result like so:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', {
  dateStyle: "short",
  timeStyle: "medium"
})
console.log(formatter.format(new Date()))
```

See [MDN Reference for `Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

However, as mentioned in the comments, you should really be storing the ISO string in your database, and format the string on the client side:

```js
const database = { post: (...args) => console.log("Posted:", ...args) }

// on form submit for example
const isoString = new Date().toISOString()
database.post({ date: isoString })

// on recieve data
const dateOfPost = new Date(isoString)
// you can format the date or do whatever you need now
console.log(dateOfPost.toString())
```

Comment: While this doesn't solve the problem itself, I appreciate the code snipets and suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: I thought the problem was that the formatter wasn't working correctly, I think this is the fix. Is there a different problem?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you should use the following library: moment.
Here is the link to their website, the documentation is pretty well done. Link to the site: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Moment js is a legacy library https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ and it's better not to use it in modern projects

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, i will continue to use it for the "moment" :)